# SUMPRODUCT but only on nonblank cells

Tags: google-sheets

Given:

```
   Lp  | COL1 | COL 2 | COL 3
 ROW 1 |   X  |       |   X
 ROW 2 |      |   X   |   X
 ROW 3 |   X  |   X   |   
 ROW 4 |      |       |
 ROW 5 |   1  |  1.5  |   2
 ROW 6 |   2  |   1   |   3
```

I would like to use `SUMPRODUCT` of Row 1 with Row 5 (and then Row 6) but only in the places where row has `X` (or rather where it is non empty).

- Expected result for Row 1: `1 * 2 + 2 * 3 = 8` (because first and last column is not empty)
- Expected result for Row 2: `1.5 * 1 + 2 * 3 = 7.5` (second and last col not empty)
- Expected result for Row 3: `1 * 2 + 1.5 * 1 = 3.5` (first and second non empty)
- Expected result for Row 4: `0`

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$D$6)*($B$7:$D$7)*(B2:D2<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing without `SUMPRODUCT`.
Create another three columns `COL1',2',3'`, replace
every `X` with the corresponding product using `IF` condition.

For example at `COL1',ROW1` you write a formula such as `=IF(A1="X", A$5\*A$6, 0)`
(here `A1` is `COL1,ROW1`)
and drag it to fill `COL1',2',3'`.
Then you do `SUM` over `COL1',2',3'`.